# Resize existing images in s3 bucket/folder

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, image-scaling

I have a thousands of existing images in s3, and I need to resize all images from one folder, and put it in another folder, but still in one bucket. Is there any solution to resize it with or without lambda? And what trigger shoud I use?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the purpose behind this?

Comment: I need a smaller images as a thumbnails, for another application. Website, admin pages, and mobile apps as well

Comment: If bucket is accessible from the lambda via http, you can have a look at [nuggan](github.com/cchantep/nuggan) (I'm a contributor of), that can be deployed as lambda.

Comment: Did you find the solution? @tukangketik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is a one-time job I would use the simplest approach:

1. Start EC2 instance.
2. Mount S3 bucket as a filesystem with [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) or [goofys](https://github.com/kahing/goofys).
3. Run ImageMagick on all the files with [scaling parameters](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than resizing the images, you could consider using a **"resize-on-the-fly" service** such as:

- [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)
- [Imgix](http://imgix.com/)

You can construct URLs that **automatically resize images to the desired size**, without having to resize and store them yourself.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, I have been implemented cloudinary and it's works well for images and other media. But I move to S3 and cloudfront because it more cost effective. Hundred thousands of images are matters for transformations and bandwidth :)

Comment: You can build your own resizer application easily, check out this repo for more information: https://github.com/sadok-f/flyimg

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Serverless Image Handler](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/answers/web-applications/serverless-image-handler/) from AWS and I'm enjoying it. It's very simple to implement!